# change SQL Server error message to another language

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How I can change SQL Server error message to another . I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Windows server 2008 r2 enterprise and want to change error message to persion language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the language like this

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
```

Comment: Not exists Persion language is language list.

Comment: If the language does not exist on the server you would have to choose a default language you are using if none matches. I believe the 33 languages of sql server are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx):

> Specifies the language environment for the session. The session
>   language determines the datetime formats and **system messages**.

I don't think there is a Persian edition though, see the list at [`sys.syslanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Persian isn't a language supported on SQL Server 2008 R2

To see the supported languages [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql)

You could also find them by using

```
 SELECT name, alias 
 FROM sys.syslanguages
```

If you then want to change the language to Italian for example use

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian
```

Further info on `SET LANGUAGE` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql)